# store few variables in a file that has a large font size with underlining

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

As of right now, we have successfully integrated Jmeter with Jenkins. We have included status checks in some of the scripts, where we write all the check's to a file.

We need to save some variables in a large font (for noting them as headers), for a scenario that has multiple thread groups, different scenario for each threadgroup. I tried a few alternative approaches, but not able to avail. Please help on this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot provide comprehensive help because we don't know how do you "store" the variables.

If you "stored" variables into a plain text file - there will be no "fonts" there.

If you want "fonts" - you need to go for one of the following options:

1. If you're using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer) you can "store" the results into HTML file where you can use i.e. [`<h1>-<h6>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements), etc. tags or [CSS styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) for controlling text size
2. If you're using [JSR223 test elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) you need to switch from plain text to i.e. one of [Office formats](https://poi.apache.org/casestudies.html) or create a [PDF file](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) instead

Answer (score 0):

Open any word processor that can generate an RTF (Rich Text Format) Document.

Produce the report your want

Save the file.

Open the RTF file in a text editor.  Not a Rich editor, but a straight text editor.

You will find a file format that supports italics, bold, underline, change in fonts, etc...

Copy the header to one file

Copy the footer to another file

Copy the body you want into your code, replacing the static information with the variable you will write out.

When you need your file with the bold, underline, italics, or combination, then write out the header, followed by the body with your dynamic run time information, followed by the footer.   YOu now have your formatted file that can be read by open source and commercial software.

Or, you could save a bunch of variables in a file and pipe them through a LaTeX build stream using the saved variables as input with your report.   This could output either an HTML report or a PDF report or both.